# OpenLayers: how to turn on visibility of a layer?

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap, openlayers-3

I can not understand what am I doing wrong ? I think I have written everything really well:

The HTML code goes like this:

```
    <b>&nbspSelect Area</b>
    <select id="mySelect_1" onchange="showSelectedArea();" > 
    <option selected disabled hidden value=''></option>"
    <option value="1">Center</option> 
    <option value="2">New jersey</option>
    </select>
```

and the Javascript is this:

```
    layer1.setVisibility(false);    
    layer2.setVisibility(false);    
    layer3.setVisibility(false);
    layer4.setVisibility(false);    

    }

    function showSelectedArea() {

    var e = document.getElementById("mySelect_1");
    var valueEpilogi_1 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    if (valueEpilogi_1 == "1") {
          layer3.setVisibility(true);   
    }

    }
```

I dont think the problem is with the if or passing the value,if I set true == true it still wont set visibility to true.I think there is a problem with triggering the function at the select tag.

Please check my external js file and tell me what is the problem?? I define all layers in init function which runs onbody load ??is tha thte problem? snk.to/f-cdh90xd4

Comment: Looks like you didn't try to narrow down the problem before asking, it's impossible to investigate for others without a working example (JSFiddle?). Do you get any maps at all? Do the layers appear if you *don't* disable their visibility first? Does it work it only `layer3` is used? How do you create your layers? How do you create your map? Looks like you'd benefid from familiarising yourself with your browser's debugger, too.

Comment: Yes, a jsFiddle would be really helpful.

Comment: Guys sorry but I am really new to programming,I am a mechanical engineering student and this is all new to me.what is jsfidle? I mean what should I post? Please guys sorry for being such a loser.Please help,this is my first stack overflow question. I get a map and layers if they are turned on.All according to plan untill there.I have one basic layer the OSM layer and 3 others that consist of geometry points,the one bein a polygon,one being a linestring and one markers made up from geometry points again!

Comment: I turn layers visibility off at function init(); on body load.

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [CodePen](http://codepen.io/pen/) is way to share your code.

Comment: I cant get js fidle to work with openlayers,here is my JS file : http://snk.to/f-cdh90xd4

Comment: Could you please reduce your example to the essential parts that are relevant to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must read the value of the select try that :

var valueEpilogi_1 = document.getElementById('mySelect_1').value ;

edit :
If you want use 'layer' outside of your init() function, it must be defined as global variable

example :

```
function init(){
/* this variable is global, declaration without  'var' before, so it can be used out of the function*/
perioxes = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Polygon Layer");
...
map.addLayer(perioxes); 
..
perioxes.setVisibility(false); 
...
}

function showSelectedArea() {

var valueEpilogi_1 = document.getElementById('mySelect_1').value ;

if (valueEpilogi_1 == "1") {
layer.setVisibility(true);   
}

}
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it wont work. And I dont see the difference from my code.It is really annoying I have been trying to come up with something for 2 days. :P

Comment: have you an error in the JS console ? check if your variables layer3 is global in your initialization function.

Comment: my friend thom,I think that this is the problem but due to my inexperience i cant tell for sure.I sitll havent founf a solution.Can you please check my js external file here: snk.to/f-cdh90xd4 ?? How do I make the layer global?

Comment: thank you so much,the thing you told me about declaring the variable without var was so helpfull and did it for me.does this apply to all js variables or only for openlayers?